# How to convert jsonstring to jsonobject in android?

Tags: java, android, json

i tried to convert jsonstring to json object. but its convert only first element.

here is my code

```
String d = [{"name":"kd","isMe":"yes","time":"10:12 AM"},{"name":"you","isMe":"no","time":"10:12 AM"}]
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(d);
```

its give following output

```
{"name":"kd","isMe":"yes","time":"10:12 AM"}
```

how can i convert this string into JSNOObject?

Comment: You should then convert the JSON Object to JSON Array. Iterate through the array and then print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this, and your root is Json array not jsonobject

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(d);
    if(jsonArray != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

            if(jsonObject == null) {
                continue;
            }

            String name = jsonObject.optString("name");
            String isMe = jsonObject.optString("isMe");
            String time = jsonObject.optString("time");

        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(my_json_string);
JSONArray jresult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("array_in_the_json_string");
```